# Help. WebResource.axd is leading to a exploit site

Tags: asp.net

I've a site hosted in a shared enviroment.

Every time I do a  and add some validation controls the ASP.Net generate a script call to a WebResource.axd who leads to a exploit site:

www2.shopezlive.com/main.php?.....

How the hacker could compromise the assemblies of .Net and how can I get rid of this mess?

Answer (score 0):

It was an FTP atack from a leaked password.

The hacker changed the .htaccess file and inject his malicious code.